# Admin and User checking not working

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have a database table named `Logins` which has 3 columns: `Username`, `Password` and `Category`. Category has two types: `Admin` and `User`.

I have a form with two textboxes where the user will write his username and password. Using the username textbox input, I want to check whether the given username is an `Admin` or `User` and based on that, open different forms.

I'm receiving the following error:

> Unexpected error:Incorrect syntax near `"'"`

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JAYI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db-ub;Integrated Security=True");
try
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Count(*) FROM Logins
                            WHERE Username=@uname and
                            Password=@pass,Category=@ctgy", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", textBox_usern.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textBox_pwd.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ctgy", c); //Can't understand how to check it

    int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result > 0)
    {
        if (c== "Admin")//this one will chek whether user is admin or user
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome Admin");
            Admin f1 = new Admin();
            f1.Show();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + textBox_usern.Text);
            FormCheck f3 = new FormCheck();
            f3.Show();
        }
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect login");
    }
    textBox_usern.Clear();
    textBox_pwd.Clear();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unexpected error:" + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Are you storing your passwords in plain text? Please don't do that.

Comment: MAV am a beginner. What should I do then? Please help

Comment: @JayitaRoy from where u r assigning value of C?

Comment: Remove `Category=@ctgy` and `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ctgy", c);`. You're not selecting based on `category`, you need to obtain it thru `username` and `pass`. After selecting using only `username` and `pass`, check to see if that row's `category == "Admin"` or `"User"`.

Comment: Sachu the problem is I can't understand what to do with Category=@ctgy

Comment: TestWell but where to put this checking?

Comment: @JayitaRoy It is recommended to hash and salt passwords using a good hashing algorithm. For more information see some of these links: [OWASP - Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet), and [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/). There are libraries you can use for this. :)

Comment: @JayitaRoy - Meda has posted an answer for where to insert the checking. It should be the correct answer. Don't forget to accept if it works for you.

Comment: @jayitaRoy check my answer..u can sort your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your program only check a user is there or not..it will not send the category back. So you should use execute reader. Which will send the detail back if a user is found. Check below code.

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JAYI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; 
    Initial Catalog=db-ub;Integrated Security=True");
    try
    {
        con.Open();
      string cat = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Username,Password,Category
        FROM Logins WHERE Username=@uname and
        Password=@pass", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", textBox_usern.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textBox_pwd.Text);

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
        //int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

       int result = 0;
       while(rdr.Read()
     {
       result++; //to confirm it entered while loop so data is there
       cat = rdr["Category"].ToString();

     }

        if (result > 0)
        {
            if (cat == "Admin")//this one will chek whether user is admin or
                                 user
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome Admin");
                Admin f1 = new Admin();
                f1.Show();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + textBox_usern.Text);
                FormCheck f3 = new FormCheck();
                f3.Show();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect login");
        }
        textBox_usern.Clear();
        textBox_pwd.Clear();
```

Comment: from where this "cat" came?

Comment: @jayitaroy after con.open() i declared a string `string cat = null;`

Comment: @jayitaRoy rename it as something else..category..or something you want

Comment: @jayitaRoy its just a varibale name you can use what ever meaningful name you want

Comment: This code is showing "Unexpected Error:Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Comment: @jayitaRoy what is your query?

Comment: is it `select username,password,category` or only `select categroy`?

Comment: I have two textbox it will get username and password and check it in database. In database there is another column named category. Through username textbox it will also check whether the user is an Admin or user

Answer (score 3):

Your query is incorrect, it misses one `and` and have extra `,`. it should be like this

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM Logins
WHERE Username=@uname and
Password=@pass and Category=@ctgy
```

Comment: Thanks but I think I am doing something wrong with the value of @ctgy too. How to check it and get the proper value. Can't understand

Comment: @JayitaRoy Where do you define `c`? We don't know how you check whether the user is an admin or user.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to read the category change your query to this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Category FROM Logins
                            WHERE Username=@uname and
                            Password=@pass", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", textBox_usern.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textBox_pwd.Text);

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
var c = reader["Category"].ToString();
   if (c== "Admin")//this one will chek whether user is admin or user
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome Admin");
        Admin f1 = new Admin();
        f1.Show();
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + textBox_usern.Text);
        FormCheck f3 = new FormCheck();
        f3.Show();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect login");
}
textBox_usern.Clear();
textBox_pwd.Clear();
```

Comment: `int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteReader();` no need

Comment: oops forgot to remove it

Comment: welcome, @JayitaRoy Accept the answer if it helped you, thanks TestWell for pointing this out

Comment: This is a more concise answer than the one accepted. Did you accept the correct answer?